# Unique index and treating multiple values as one SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BigTable]
(
    [BigTableId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MuchText] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [smallint] NOT NULL
    (...)
)
```

The column `MuchText` can store any text value and column `Type` can store numbers 1, 2, 3, 4.

I would like to create unique index, or something that will give me the similar results, on `MuchText` and `Type` columns (so the combination of both values would be forced to be unique).

But here's the problem - I would like to treat some values in `Type` column as one. Let me explain how it should work:

1. It is forbidden to insert record with values `Type = 1` and `MuchText = 'XXX'` if the record with values `Type = 1` and `MuchText = 'XXX'` already exists
2. It is forbidden to insert record with values `Type = 1` and `MuchText = 'XXX'` if the record with values `Type = 2` and `MuchText = 'XXX'` already exists
3. It is forbidden to insert record with values `Type = 1` and `MuchText = 'XXX'` if the record with values `Type = 3` and `MuchText = 'XXX'` already exists

   etc. etc. for types 1/2/3, but for Type = 4 it should behave like a classic unique index:
4. For `Type = 4`, it is forbidden to insert record with values `Type = 4` and `MuchText = 'XXX'` if the record with values `Type = 4` and `MuchText = 'XXX'` already exists

So this should not be possible:

1. Type = 1, MuchText = 'XXX'
2. Type = 2, MuchText = 'XXX' (not allowed, because there is already a record with Type = 1 and the same MuchText value).

But this is OK:

1. Type = 1, MuchText = 'XXX'
2. Type = 4, MuchText = 'XXX'

Comment: Have you considered writing a trigger to enforce the constraints you mentioned?

Comment: Yup, it can be done this way. I was just wondering whether there are other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Filtered Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) using `CREATE INDEX ... WHERE (cond)`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_BigTable123 ON BigTable (MuchText)
WHERE Type IN (1, 2, 3)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_BigTable4 ON BigTable (MuchText)
WHERE Type = 4
```

Comment: Thought about creating trigger, but it seems to be the best answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a computed column that has the same value for all types that should be grouped together (`Grp` below) and include that in the constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BigTable](
    [BigTableId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MuchText] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    Grp AS CASE WHEN [Type] IN (1,2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
    UNIQUE(Grp, MuchText)
    )
```